# Applying the Implicit Function Theorem to solve a system

Tags: real-analysis, implicit-function-theorem

Let $h:R\to R$ be a $C^1$ function, $h(0)=0$. Consider the system $$e^x+h(y)=u^2 \\ e^y-h(x)=v^2$$
Prove that there is a neighborhood $V$ of $(1,1)$ such that for all $(u,v)\in V$ there is a solution $(x,y)$.

Is my solution correct?

Consider $F: (x,y,u,v)\mapsto (e^x+h(y)-u^2,e^y-h(x)-v^2)$. It is $C^1$, with $F(0,0,1,1)=(0,0)$. The Jacobian determinant w.r.t. the first two variables at $(0,0)$ is  $1+h'(0)^2$. So there is an open set $V\subset R^2$ containing $(1,1)$ and a $C^1$ function $g=(g_1,g_2):V\to R^2$ such that $g(1,1)=(0,0)$ and $F(g_1(u,v),g_2(u,v),u,v)=(0,0)$ for all $(u,v)\in V$. That is, there is a local solution  $(x,y)=(g_1(u,v),g_2(u,v))$.

Comment: Looks good to me. I would write something along the lines "So, the implicit function theorem shows that there is an open...".

Comment: Also note that the implicit function theorem not only gives you just a function, but it also assures that the function is _continuous_.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2712517/prove-the-existence-of-a-solution-to-the-system-by-using-the-implicit-function-t

Comment: @onurcanbektas I believe it even says that the function is continuously differentiable.

Comment: @user5579085 Yes, you are right, since $h$ is of class $C^1$, the resulting function is, also, of class $C^1$. Thanks for pointing out.